# jQuery: how to implement controller for slider (carousel)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I have build a slider using jQuery which works fine. It was a quick development so that didn't get time to add controller. Right now it is getting hard to fix controller for the carousel.

[image]

Does any one have solution or alternative to fix this?

Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/Pn2UB/16/**

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
function slider(container) {
    var currPg = null,
        firstPg = null;
    container.find('> .pg').each(function (idx, pg) {
        pg = $(pg);
        var o = {
            testimonial: pg.find('> .testimonial'),
            thumb: pg.find('> .testimonial-thumb'),
            pg: pg
        };
        o.pg.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
        });

        if (idx > 0) {
            o.pg.css({
                opacity: 0,
                    'z-index': -1
            });
            o.testimonial.css({
                'margin-left': '100%'
            });
            o.thumb.css({
                'bottom': '-100%'
            });
        } else {
            firstPg = o;
        }
        o.prev = currPg;
        if (currPg) {
            currPg.next = o;
        }
        currPg = o;
    });
    firstPg.prev = currPg;
    currPg.next = firstPg;
    currPg = firstPg;

    this.advance = function advance(duration) {
        console.log("advance!", this);
        var dur = duration || $.fx.speeds._default;
        var dur2 = Math.ceil(dur / 2);

        var dh = container.height();
        var dw = container.width();
        var nextPg = currPg.next;

        nextPg.pg.css({
            opacity: 1,
                'z-index': null
        });

        var _pg = currPg;
        currPg.testimonial.stop().animate({
            'margin-left': -dw
        }, dur, function () {
            _pg.pg.css({
                opacity: 0,
                    'z-index': -1
            });
            _pg = null;
        });
        nextPg.testimonial.stop()
            .css({
            'margin-left': dw
        })
            .animate({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, dur);
        currPg.thumb.stop().animate({
            'bottom': -dh
        }, dur2, function () {
            nextPg.thumb.stop()
                .css({
                'bottom': -dh
            })
                .animate({
                'bottom': 0
            }, dur2);
            nextPg = null;
        });
        currPg = nextPg;
    }
}
var s = new slider($('#banner'));

function scheduleNext() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        s.advance();
        scheduleNext();
    }, 5000);
}
scheduleNext();
```

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "controller", be more specific about it's purpose.  Since your code looks like it was hit by a truck you might want to consider adding comments as well.

Comment: @MikeHometchko controller for slider that mean `next` for move to to slide and `prev` to show previous slider. I would like to get an advice or suggestion which is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to add a variable direction and change that on click of both prev and next

```
var direction = 'left';



$('#next').click(function(event) {
    direction = 'right';
    s.advance(1000,direction);
});
$('#prev').click(function(event) {
    direction = 'left';
    s.advance(1000,direction);
});
```

then add a line where it checks the direction variable

```
    if(direction == 'left')
        var dw = container.width();
    else if(direction =='right')
        var dw = - container.width();
    else{
        console.log('Wrong direction')
        return;
    }
```

[Carosal fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn2UB/18/)

Don't forget to add argument on advanced function

Answer (score 1):

For next slider you need:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
s.advance();
});
```

But anyway you have to construct universal animations methods with parameters.
Check this examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/pjTU2/
and
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html

Comment: next time I will do that way. Thanks for your advice and suggestion